# Android on Mac: Cocoa AWT: Running on AppKit thread 0 when not expected

Tags: android, livecode

I get the following error in terminal when trying to start an `AVD`:
I can't start the `AVD`, I get this `Cocoa/Java` error

```
Last login: Sun Mar 16 11:47:41 on ttys000
MuadDib:~ yeldarb$ /Users/yeldarb/Desktop/LiveCode/android-sdk-macosx/tools/android ; exit;
2014-03-16 11:47:56.619 java[1014:2307] Cocoa AWT: Running on AppKit thread 0 when not expected. (
   0   liblwawt.dylib                      0x000000010c377a13 +[AWTStarter start:swtMode:swtModeForWebStart:] + 231
   1   liblwawt.dylib                      0x000000010c3786c8 JNI_OnLoad + 735
   2   libjava.dylib                       0x00000001077cb509 Java_java_lang_ClassLoader_00024NativeLibrary_load + 207
   3   ???                                 0x0000000108022bd1 0x0 + 4429327313
   4   ???                                 0x0000000108016f98 0x0 + 4429279128
   5   ???                                 0x0000000108017290 0x0 + 4429279888
)
2014-03-16 11:47:56.620 java[1014:2307]    Please file a bug report at [edited] with this message and a reproducible test case.
```

Comment: When asking a question on SO, please include a genuine question, e.g. "What is causing this error?". Also, give as much detail about what you are trying to do as possible, e.g. "I am trying to compile and test a stack in the Android emulator from within LiveCode" and add proper tags (LiveCode, rather than Java, OSX and Cocoa in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You should do a proper install of the Android SDK. Don't install this stuff on your desktop. If you installed the Android SDK on e.g. a school computer without having admin permissions, ask the administrator to install it.